# Heuristic Algorithms Implementation

Tags: python, heuristics, metaheuristics

As a new python learner, I'm supposed to implement either GENETIC ALGORITHM or TABU SEARCH. Which one would be easier for me? Both of them are constructed for the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Genetic algorithm is a lot wider family of algorithm that is a lot more tuneable. It kinda depends on your problem space whether TABU search is sensible but i would recommend implementing tabu search which basically a variation of random search.